# how to filter users who are not being followed in django

Tags: python, django

Friends, I am using django-friendship with django 1.9 to implement user follows. But on a 'users to follow' page, I want to filter those users who aren't being followed by the current user. How should I implement this?

Here is my views.py

```
def users_to_follow(request):
    follow = Follow.objects.following(request.user)
    all_users = User.objects.all().exclude(follow)
    return render(request,"auths/users_to_follow.html",locals())
```

and here is my users_to_follow.html

```
{% for u in all_users %}
  {{ u.username }}
  <a href="{% url 'follow' u.username %}">Follow</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I think there is something wrong with views.py . But i haven't been able to figure it out. Help me friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `follow` name (variable) is a list of user objects. You can get the IDs of those users like these:

```
follow = Follow.objects.following(request.user)
follow_ids = [x.id for x in follow]
```

And then use `exclude` like this:

```
to_follow = User.objects.all().exclude(id__in=follow)
```

The `to_follow` list should contain the users you want.

Answer (score 0):

`exclude` does not work this way. You can try the following:

```
def users_to_follow(request):
    all_users = User.objects.exclude(following__follower=request.user)
    return render(request,"auths/users_to_follow.html",locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Django QuerySet [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#id4) (emphasis mine):

> Field lookups are how you specify the meat of an SQL WHERE clause. They’re specified as **keyword arguments** to the QuerySet methods filter(), exclude() and get().

So, your `exclude()` method call can be adjusted as

```
all_users = User.objects.all().exclude(pk=follow)
```

And that's it!